# How to load .mat file and convert it to .csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab

I wanted to load .mat file and to convert it to .csv file.

This is for MacOS terminal, running python3.7. In the past I've loaded .csv and .dat files.
Following is the code I wrote to write for above task.

```py
mat_274 = load('ecgca274_edfm.mat')
T = struct2table(mat_274)
writetable(T, 'ecgca274_edfm.csv', 'Delimiter', ',')
print(mat_274)
```

After running the above code, I'm getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bayesian3.py", line 1, in <module>
    mat_274 = load('ecgca274_edfm.mat')
NameError: name 'load' is not defined
```

Can anyone help to correct errors or suggest a new way for this conversion task ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer for my above question. Code Snippet is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io import loadmat

data_dict = loadmat('ecgca274_edfm.mat')
data_array = data_dict['val']
data_array = data_array.transpose(1, 0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_array,
                  columns=['ch'+str(n) for n in range(1,7)])
```

Rather than converting into csv, as I asked in the original question, I have converted it to a dataframe for further processing.

Comment: @Manish the key of the data array was 'val'

Answer (score 2):

There is a function in scipy for this operation, as described on their documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

```
import scipy.io
mat_274 = scipy.io.loadmat( 'ecgca274_edfm.mat' )
```

However, it is also very picky about the version of MATLAB used to generate the *.mat file. In the link above is the following warning:

```
v4 (Level 1.0), v6 and v7 to 7.2 matfiles are supported.

You will need an HDF5 python library to read MATLAB 7.3 format mat files. 
Because scipy does not supply one, we do not implement the HDF5 / 7.3 interface here.
```

One potential way to get around this problem is by saving it as an older mat version in MATLAB. The following command should do this (in MATLAB):

```
save( 'ecgca274_edfm.mat', '-v7' )
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use loadmat() and it worked in my case. My actual question is on converting to csv after loading .mat file.

Comment: After chaging to loadmat(), now the following error appeared. ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bayesian4.py", line 7, in <module>
    T = struct2table(mat_274)
NameError: name 'struct2table' is not defined```

Comment: I'd like to point out something this is also mentioned in the `loadmat `docs - `loadmat` is only good for relatively old `.mat` files, and that newer files require loading through HDF5-compatible tools.